# undefined is not a function : node error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I am trying to run static.js, command :

```
node static.js
```

I am getting the error :

```
 libpath.exists(filename, function (exists) {
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is my code snap of static.js :

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var filename = libpath.join(path, uri);

libpath.exists(filename, function (exists) {
    if (!exists) {
        response.writeHead(404, {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        });
        response.write("404 Not Found\n");
        response.end();
        return;
    }
```

I have defined libpath at the beginning

```
var libpath = require('path')
```

Comment: where is `libpath` defined?

Comment: It seems like @Houseman is right. libpath is not defined anywhere. Also, using console.log() or debugger is a great way to debug undefined errors.

Comment: Hi, I have defined libpath at the beginning. I forgot to mention, I have edited my question as well.

Comment: Why do you think [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) should have an `exists` method?

Comment: It looks like you're not exporting things correctly. You need to show the imported `libpath` code.

Comment: the exists function is defined in the file system module, https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback, see my answer below

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much @BhavO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exists function is not defined in the path module, its defined as part of the  the file system ('fs') module:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.exists(filename, function (exists) { });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BhavO :)